# Function won't render elements in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React so bear with me please. Here's my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  var state = {
    people:
      [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Jhon",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Ben",
        }
      ]
  }
  var get_names = () =>
  {
    state.people.map(people => {
      return <p>{people.name}</p>
    })
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
     {
      get_names()
     }
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And for some reason, it won't generate any elements.
However, the code works if I'm not using a function like this:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
     {
        state.people.map(people => {
          return <p>{people.name}</p>
        })
     }
    </div>
  );
```

I tried this method:

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
     {
      this.get_names()
     }
    </div>
  );
```

But it gives me this is undefined.

Then I tried this instead:

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
     {
      () => this.get_names()
     }
    </div>
  );
```

But once again, nothing renders.
This is probably a rookie's mistake, but can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Here's a live demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/404mjv65rx

Comment: Both answers below are valid: While [Tholle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55196416/4035) returns explicitly, [Nafees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55196454/4035)'s implicitly. Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `get_names`. Add the `return` keyword and it will work as expected.

```
var get_names = () => {
  return state.people.map(people => {
    return <p key={people.id}>{people.name}</p>;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need curly braces here

```
var get_names = () => state.people.map(people => <p>{people.name}</p>)
```

or explicitly return map

```
var get_names = () => {
    return state.people.map(people => {
      return <p>{people.name}</p>
    })
  }
```